# Permission denied when trying to execute a program as root on CentOS

Tags: centos, permissions

I am logged as root on a CentOS server but I am not able to run a program.

I have compiled using cc a basic helloworld program, trying to run it outputs:

`bash: ./a.out: Permission denied`

I have tried to `chmod +x a.out` but no success.

The rights seems to be ok:

`-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root 6426 Nov 15 10:50 a.out*`

I don't know what this "*" means.

Comment: Doing this, or much of anything, as root is a very bad idea. Stop now, and use your normal user account.

Comment: The asterisk means the file is executable. What is the output from <code>file a.out</code>?

Comment: No output: Permission denied as stated above, it is just a basic c program containing a helloworld.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for your advices. I am doing my best to produce a minimal case reproducing my error. Actually I had the problem trying to build `ncdu` in order to install it... Do you also recommend doing this with a normal user account?

Comment: ncdu is in the EPEL repository. Why are you trying to compile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to guess that filesystem that is underlying the directory the file is in is mounted with the `noexec` attribute which will disable the execution of files.

Comment: I moved the file annnnddd it works ;) Thanks. Do you know how to check that ?

Comment: Yes I do. you can learn too by looking at the man page for [mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount). Regarding the `*` you should look at the man page for [ls](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ls).

Comment: Since I am not mounting this manually, but the system does, I thought it was a kind of non trivial, non RTFM question. But as you wish.

Comment: Oh no, it's completely trivial.